# Strange behavior when assigning value to an element in a char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm really confused by the bug I encountered tonight. When assigning value to an element in an array, another element is changed and I can't figure out what happened. And I don't know if I used `sizeof()` correctly. However they seem to work fine after adding intensive output statement. The problem appears to be in line 11, but I have no idea on how to fix it. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void addstr(char ***arr, const char *str, int *size){
  char *my_str=(char *)calloc(strlen(str)+1,sizeof(char));
  strcpy(my_str,str);
  char **new_arr=realloc(*arr,sizeof(*arr)+sizeof(char*));
  /*for (int i=0;i<*size;i++)
    printf("%s\n",new_arr[i]);*/
  new_arr[*size]=my_str;
  /*for (int i=0;i<*size;i++)
    printf("%s\n",new_arr[i]);*/
  *arr=new_arr;
  *size=*size+1;
}

int main(){
  char **mystery=0;
  int size=0;
  const char *ptr1="test1";
  const char *ptr2="test2";
  const char *ptr3="test3";
  const char *ptr4="test4";
  const char *ptr5="test5";
  const char *ptr6="test6";
  addstr(&mystery,ptr1,&size);
  addstr(&mystery,ptr2,&size);
  addstr(&mystery,ptr3,&size);
  addstr(&mystery,ptr4,&size);
  addstr(&mystery,ptr5,&size);
  addstr(&mystery,ptr6,&size);
  int i;
  printf("\nresult:\n\nsize: %d\n",size);
  for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("%s\n",mystery[i]);
}
```

The output is

```
result:

size: 6
test1

test3
test4
test5
test6
```

`test2` somehow is changed. This is driving me mad cause I'm still new to `c` and don't know where exactly went wrong. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `sizeof(*arr)`....seems wrong....

Comment: fixed! i changed to (*size +1)*sizeof(char*)) THANKS!!!

Comment: Your fix seems wrong - is a `*` missing in your comment?

Comment: @4386427 I count 2 missing `*`. It should be: `(*size +1)*sizeof(char*))`

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - good catch - I only spotted one of them

Comment: ur right! I was so exited about the fix that I had a few typos. The program works and thank you all!